# MySQL Min Date Selction with grouping

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have the table below:

```
UID  productName productDate  ...

1     productOne  10/1/2020
2     productOne  13/1/2020
3     productOne  14/1/2020
4     productTwo  10/1/2020
5     productTwo  18/1/2020
6     productFour  13/1/2020
7     productFive  11/1/2020
```

I'm trying to get product name and first entry date  only for products that arrived today.

```
    cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT j.productName, Min(j.productDate)" +
        " FROM (SELECT * FROM maintable ORDER BY productDate) as t " +
        " JOIN (SELECT * FROM maintable WHERE productDate=@currentDate) as j" +
        " ON j.productName = t.productName" +
        " group by productName", cnn);
```

I have managed to get productName and Min productDate for every entry in table, but I can't filter it for the only products that arrived today.

Thank you.

Comment: I think i've got it. I've swapped ("SELECT j.productName, Min(j.productDate)" to: ("SELECT t.productName, Min(t.productDate)"

Comment: `group by productName` must cause "ambiguous name" error. Replace `ON j.productName = t.productName` with `USING (productName)` for to use the column name without table alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT productName, MIN(productDate) min_productDate
FROM maintable 
GROUP BY productName
HAVING MAX(productDate) = CURRENT_DATE
```

PS. The date format shown in sample data is wrong for MySQL, must be `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: Perfect. Date format was for display only etc. Can you please explain min_productDate entry?

Comment: @michal This is an alias - the name assigned to this expression for referencing in the query (if needed) and in client code (instead of positional referring).